# how to map list inside class to single object with mapsturct

Tags: java, regex, spring-boot, java-8, automapper

I want to convert my list inside class to single object.

From :

Class School

```
private List<SchoolAccount> schoolAccounts;
```

Class SchoolAccount

```
private Integer schoolId;
```

to :

Class SchoolDto

```
private Integer schoolId;
```

My mapper class

```
@Mapper
public interface SchoolMapper {

    SchoolMapper INSTANCE= Mappers.getMapper(SchoolMapper.class);

@Mapping(source = "schoolId", target = "SchoolAccount.schoolId")
    void mergeschoolIdDto(SchoolDto, @MappingTarget School School);
```

Answer (score 0):

yours SchoolAccount is a list ,so you have multiple schoolId,

if you want a SchoolDto List, you can use java8 stream.

```
schoolAccounts.stream().map(item->new SchoolDto(item.getSchoolId())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```